# Differentiate between address, city, state, zip in UISearchBar

Tags: ios, nsstring, uisearchbar

One of the parameters my iOS application must meet is searching in full or partially by address, city, state, and zipcode.

I cannot depend on users using commas to separate the data. I also do cannot scan a string for a zip code since the street number could potentially be 5 digits.

I was wondering what standard practice was used to analyze this sort of input. Any help or reference would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One (slightly inefficient) way of doing this would be to make a call to Google's [Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/). You'll get results with [address component types](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types), such as `street_address`, `postal_code`, `administrative_area_level_n`, etc.

Hope this helps!